# Parse HTML DOM after executing JavaScript with jSoup or other lib

Tags: java, javascript, html, dom, jsoup

I want to parse an expanded doodle.com poll with jSoup 
There are two Problems for me. I don't know how to execute the JavaScript before parsing the DOM and second I must click a button before that to extend for all dates.

What i got so far:

```
Response response= Jsoup.connect("http://doodle.com/xyz")
           .ignoreContentType(true)
           .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")  
           .referrer("http://www.google.com")   
           .timeout(12000) 
           .followRedirects(true)
           .execute();

Document doc = response.parse();
System.out.print(doc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.2/)? You can interact with the page and then scrape any results from the dom you like using jQuery selectors. It's really nice.

```
import groovy.grape.Grape

@Grab(group="org.gebish", module="geb-core", version="0.9.0-RC-1")
@Grab(group="org.seleniumhq.selenium", module="selenium-firefox-driver", version="2.28.0")

import geb.Browser

def browser = new Browser()
browser.go "http://doodle.com/xyz"
browser.find(".maybefind").find("a", 0).click()
browser.find("a").each({
        element -> println element.text()
    })
browser.quit()
```

Save it as a .groovy and run it with

```
groovy yourScript.groovy
```

Comment: I have no experience in using groovy. I also found the hint of using selenium or HtmlUnit. But I hope that there is another easy solution.

Comment: Geb is about as easy as it gets. Groovy is a superset of Java, so if you want to use Java Static concepts you are welcome to do so. Almost all valid Java is also valid Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

JSoup is just an HTML parser/"tidyfier" - not a browser emulator. To interact with HTML pages (execute javascript, fill out forms, etc.) you should use a tool like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).